# Merge 1000 CSV files by One specified column, when multiple columns are repeated

Tags: python, r, csv, merge

I need to merge multiple CSV files, which will each look like the excerpt below (file size ~170 Kb each). In each case, the first 3 columns will be identical in every CSV file. I would like to generate one merged CSV file, merging by the information from the first column "`mrID`" (the next two columns that are also in common among all files, `chr` and `pos`, are not good / not unique identifiers for later rows). I would like to have the final merged file contain just this identifier "`mrID`" one time in the first row, and then have the final row from each of the CSV files with the column header "`sum`".

```
mrID    chr pos main    GxE epi sum
cA  2   0   0   4   1   5
cB  2   5   3   2   1   6
cC  2   10  2   0   2   4
```

In the end, the merged file should look like:

```
mrID    sumCSV1 sumCSV2
cA  5 3
cB  6 4
cC  4 7
```

I searched and found some options with "cat" for merging files, but my implementation made it append new rows to the merged CSV file and also messed up some of the order.

If it would simplify the merging I can probably alter my 1000 CSV files to omit the unnecessary columns `(ie, delete columns chr/pos/main/GxE/epi).`

I also made some attempts based on the entires for "[Merge multiple csv's using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17849308/merge-multiple-csvs-using-python)" but am getting Syntax errors, and wondering if it is valid that I modified the code from that question to read as `list_of_files = ['*.csv']` rather than naming the csvs (but with `1000 csvs`, I don't want to name them all in the python code).

Thank you in advance! I'm inexperienced in Python but was trying this thinking it may be too much data for R; I'm a little more experienced in R but even there mainly in running stats packages / less in data parsing.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  I can't see the logic that, given the input data, generates a 3 for mrID `cA`, a 4 for mrID `cB`, and a 7 for mrID `cC`.  Please describe more clearly, with a second CSV sample file if necessary, how to obtain the desired output from the given input(s).

Comment: take a look at `rbind_all` from the r package `dplyr`.  
Or try `do.call(rbind,list_of_data)`

Comment: The entires in my columns are longer so I had shortened/abbreviated them, so the real file isn't cA etc. The header names in full are: mrID, chr, pos, main, GxE, epistasis, sum. The first row of data is c2.2:14280, 2, 0, 0.664977764, 0.223160248, 6.238330565, 5.398073797.

Comment: In more detail, for the broad context, I need to (1) randomize my data 1000 times; (2) run a script 1000 times -- once on each random dataset; (3) merge the 1000 outputs and analyze. I am trying to do this for a permutation test. I figured out how to randomize using the R command sample; I'm working to learn a for loop for the 1000 randomizations/script runs. Step 3 however is puzzling me; in the past I've used the R/merge function but that's impractical for this many files.